# Python 3 на Windows 7. imaplib error

Tags: python, windows-7, imap

Не большой скрипт для проверки не прочитанных сообщений, при запуске из файла выдает следущее:

```
 C:\check_mail>c:\Python33\python.exe check.py 
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "check.py", line 1, in
 <module>
     import imaplib   File "c:\Python33\lib\imaplib.py", line 25,
 in <module>
     import binascii, errno, random, re, socket, subprocess, sys, time,
 calendar   
 File "c:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
         import _socket ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный
     модуль.
```

Если все ввести в интерпритатор, то все отрабатывает.

Листинг:

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('nameserver')
mail.login('login', 'password')
mail.select('INBOX')

num = len(mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN')[1][0].split())
print (num)
```

Comment: Почему-то отсутствет C-extension для работы с сокетами. Попробуй переустановить Python. Рекомендую также попробовать версию 2.7 - может это баг, специфичный для 3000-ветки.

Comment: А если 2.х удалить, а 3.х оставить- будет ли воспроизводится ошибка? Некоторые поисковые результаты по данной проблеме говорят, что это возможно конфликт двух версий на одной машине.

Comment: @vorlog, значит не то.

Comment: @vorlog,
1. а если явно указать  

    #! c:\Python33\
?  
2. Попробуйте удалить все версии питона и заново установить только используемую.   
3. Что находится в sys.path ?

Comment: Уже удалял и ставил заново, явно указать тоже не помогает, в sys.path все верно и соответствует 3.2 activestate.

Comment: А если попробовать изменить битность питона? Например если стоит 64, поставить 32 и наоборот.

Comment: У меня 32 битная win7 64 битную версию ставить не дает, что логично. Как можно описать библиотеку python27.dll?